# Who made the alethiometer and how?

Tags: his-dark-materials

In *Northern Lights*, the alethiometers were said to have been made in Prague in the 17th century, and it is later suggested that their creation is parallel to the Scientific Revolution in Europe in our universe.

In *The Book of Dust* Malcolm asks my question: "Why don't they make another one?" The answer given is rather minimal "parts of it are made of an alloy that can't be made anymore".

Who made the alethiometers in Prague over 300 years ago, and how did they do it?

Comment: You may have to wait for parts 2 and / or 3 of The Book of Dust to get an answer to that one.